# how to print last part of a string in shell script

Tags: string, shell, awk

I have this line:

```
102:20620453:d=2017021012:UGRD:10 m above ground:15 hour fcst::lon=79.500000,lat=9.000000,val=-5.35
```

Now I want to just print the value -5.35 from this line and nothing else.

I also want this command to be able to extract the -7.04 from this line and nothing else.

```
102:20620453:d=2017021012:UGRD:10 m above ground:15 hour fcst::lon=280.500000,lat=11.000000,val=-7.04
```

I have read the other stack overflow questions and they did not seem to quite get at what I was looking for.  I noticed that they did you awk or sed.  What types of things should I do to be able to extract just the part of the above lines after val=?

Comment: Is `val` absolutely, positively guaranteed to be the last field in each line -- not just for the current version of the log string, but all future versions as well? Personally, I'd be wary of making such an assumption.

Comment: BTW -- are you one processing one line at a time, or a whole file at a go? It makes a big difference in performance: You're better off using `awk` for big streams, whereas if you're going a line at a time, using bash builtins will save the (significant) cost of starting up an external process. (That is: The answer by anubhava is much slower than mine if you're just running one copy of awk per line of logging, but it's much faster to take anubhava's awk and give it 20MB of logs to parse all at once than to use bash-builtin string manipulation in a loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for `awk`, `sed`, or any other external tool: bash has its own built-in regular expression support, via the `=~` operator to `[[ ]]`, and the `BASH_REMATCH` array (populated with matched contents).

```
val_re='[, ]val=([^ ]+)'
line='102:20620453:d=2017021012:UGRD:10 m above ground:15 hour fcst::lon=79.500000,lat=9.000000,val=-5.35'
[[ $line =~ $val_re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

---

That said, if you **really** want to remove everything up to and including the string `val=` (and thus to have your code break if other values were added to the format in the future), you could also do so like this:

```
val=${line##*val=}  # assign everything from $line after the last instance of "val=" to val
```

The syntax here is [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). See also [BashFAQ #100: How do I do string manipulations in bash?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk with field separator as `=` and print last field:

```
awk -F'=' '{print $NF}' <<< "$str"

-5.35
```

Answer (score 0):

this will search the string val= from the end and give anything after that

```
str='102:20620453:d=2017021012:UGRD:10 m above ground:15 hour fcst::lon=79.500000,lat=9.000000,val=-5.35'

echo "$str" | grep -Po '(?<=val=).*'
```

answer works on GNU grep only

Comment: ...the full list of features *guaranteed* to be available in `grep` is given in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html. Not that it isn't okay to write a StackOverflow answer that depends on extensions, but it should be called out when an answer only works on GNU grep, modern BSD grep, or another specific implementation. (And actually, even with GNU grep, `-P` support depends on compile-time flags that can only be enabled on systems with libpcre).

Comment: ...re: `echo $str`, see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), or run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and follow the link in the warning to [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086).

Comment: You've corrected the quoting problem, but your answer still doesn't mention that use of `-P` requires _GNU_ `grep`. Enclosing the regex in `"..."` rather than `'...'` is ill-advised, unless you intentionally want to embed shell variable references. `[^$]` makes no sense here (it matches any char. _except_ (`^`) a _literal_ `$`) - you probably meant just `.`. Finally. please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).